# sharepoint 2010 jquery webservices

Tags: jquery, web-services, sharepoint

i have a tag cloud on my master page. I would like to redirect links of the tags within that tag cloud to another url (script below).

The script runs fine when i test it with the console in firefox but it doesn't work when i put it in the head of my master.

After investigation i have noticed that my script is loaded before a sharepoint webservice /_vti_bin/SocialDataService.asmx/GetAllTagTerms

which could be the reason!

**My question is: would it be possible to use jquery to call that webservice and make it work?**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var $sel = $("#tagscloud a[href*='tagprofile.aspx?termid=']");

    var rootUrl = $('#ctl00_RootUrlId').val();



    $sel.each(function () {

        var $this = $(this), href = $this.attr('href');

        $this.attr('href', rootUrl + 'Recherche/Pages/Results.aspx?k=SocialTagId%3A%22' + href.slice(href.indexOf('tagprofile.aspx?termid=') + 23) + '%22');

    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the method `TagCloudItemsRender` in SocialData.js does not have any events you can hook into.

What you could do, is wait for the `tagCloudData` element to be created

```
var timer = setInterval(function() { 
    var cloud = $("#tagCloudData"); //need better selector if multiple tag clouds on same page
    if(cloud) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        //do your code here
    }
}, 1000)
```